# I deleted a page on website but it's still showing up 24 hours later

Tags: web-server, cache

Yesterday as I was uploading changes to a website that I'm working on the server stopped showing the changed files. After making several changes to the file and repeatedly uploading it to no avail, I deleted the file on the server. Hoping that it would now show a 404 error when I cleared the cache in my browser and refreshed the page, I was sorely disappointed.

Does anyone have any suggestions on things to try? It is an A2 Hosting reseller account.

Comment: after making sure, that you have uploaded you content into the correct DocumentRoot, the only cause is cache in between. try to send '?' at the end of your address in the browser to make sure that you also bypass any cache, if there is any in between.like: http://www.text.com/??

Comment: @ZarehK This was my first thought. Therefore I cleared the cache and refreshed the page and still got the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the culprit. Apparently there was an .htaccess file outside of the root folder that was using a redirect from this URI to a duplicate file of it on the server. After deleting that .htaccess file (as it wasn't needed) and then refreshing the page I now got the desired result. I am working on a redesign of a site that was created by someone else so I'm not quite sure why that .htaccess file was there or why there were duplicate files. Thank you guys for your suggestions though.

Comment: Good one!  Select your answer as the answer to the question so everyone can see that it's handled, and anyone referring to this in the future can see.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are working on the correct document root path of the website and do a test from another system/proxy URL.

Comment: ALong the same lines, try accessing a file in the same directory that you know is NOT there, and verify you get 404.  Then create the file using the same path and methods; see if the file appears.  If not, most likely you're not editing the working copies.

Comment: @Ryan This wasn't even a question as I had just made changes to the homepage that reflected instantly. When I couldn't get this page to reflect the changes I deleted it on the server and then attempted to access it from a browser hoping to see a 404 error. When the same page still showed up I had friends and family in other states access the link and they saw the same thing.

Comment: @JeffLearman I tried this as well and got the same thing. This is why I'm scratching my head and pulling my hair out.